# What is wrong with my Sub select statement?

Tags: sql

When I run this query it produces a result of zero.  I know there is supposed to be a result of the longest length movie with that actor, but don't know what I am doing wrong in my sub select.  Thoughts?

```
SELECT film.length,film.title
FROM moviedb.film,moviedb.actor,moviedb.film_actor
WHERE film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
AND film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
AND actor.first_name = "Salma"
AND actor.last_name = "Nolte"
AND film.length = (SELECT MAX(film.length) FROM moviedb.film);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the problem.  The problem is that the film that has the maximum length does not meet the other criteria in the `where` clause.  That is simple.

You should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax in your queries.